# How do I separate the valid and invalid responses from my API

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using an API called CarJam. I want to open a panel when a valid number plate is entered in the input box.

Currently what happens when I run the code it will work when I enter a valid number plate and but if enter a invalid number plate it will return 'null' and if I enter it again it will return what it is meant which is the error. But I just need to separate the null response from the valid ones

```
private const string key = "x";
public string url = "https://test.carjam.co.nz/a/vehicle:abcd?&key=";
public string plate;
InputField outputBox;
public GameObject inputBox;
public string input;
public GameObject Panel;

void Start()
{
    outputBox = GameObject.Find("OutputBox").GetComponent<InputField>();
}

public void OpenPanel()
{
    if (Panel != null)
    {
        bool isActive = Panel.activeSelf; 
        Panel.SetActive(!isActive);
    }
}

public void GetData() => StartCoroutine(GetData_Coroutine());

public void GetInput()
{
    input = inputBox.GetComponent<Text>().text;
    plate = input;
}

IEnumerator GetData_Coroutine()
{
    outputBox.text = "Loading...";
    GetInput();
    string uri = (url + key + "&plate=" + plate);

    using(UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
    {
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.isNetworkError|| request.isHttpError)
        {   
            outputBox.text = request.error;
            plate = string.Empty;
            GetInput();
        }
        else
        {   
            outputBox.text = request.downloadHandler.text;
            Open
            plate = string.Empty;
            GetInput();
        }            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse json respoce to c# object and then you can perorm conditional check according to your need. Unity provide default json parser [see here.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not very experienced with C# but I am not sure how the parse json would help. Also some more detail on the issue: The API outputs I want to seperate are 'null' and 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request' (the invalid number plate response) and I want to seperate them from the valid API outputs that are something like '{"plate":"","replacement_plate":"","year_of_manufacture":"2000","make":"Suzuki","model":"RM125","submodel":"","vin":"","chassis":"","engine_no":"","cc_rating":0,"main_colour":"","second_colour":"","body_style":"","vehicle_type":"","reported_stolen":"Y","country_of_

Comment: use UnityWebRequest.responseCode to get responce code and they accordingly you can seprate the output [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-responseCode.html)